# Image classification using cascaded boosting in scikit-learn - why would classification terminate early?

Tags: python-2.7, computer-vision, scikit-learn, scikit-image, cascade-classifier

I've pasted all my code here in case you'd need that to understand my question: [Plotting a graph on axes but getting no results while trying to classify image based on HoG features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178535/plotting-a-graph-on-axes-but-getting-no-results-while-trying-to-classify-image-b)

My question is: given approximately 500 images (the Caltech "[Cars 2001](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/archive.html)" dataset) with 48 HoG features each, what possible reasons can there be for the boosting to terminate early? What could cause a perfect fit, or a problem with the boosted sample weights, and how can such problems be solved? The specific algorithm I'm using is SAMME, a multiclass Adaboost classifier. I'm using Python 2.7 on Anaconda.

When I checked certain variables during the classification of my dataset, setting the `n_estimators` parameter to be 600, I found that:

- discrete_test_errors: consisted of 1 item instead of being an array of 600 values
- discrete_estimator_errors: was again one single value instead of of being an array of 600 values
- real_test_errors is just one item again instead of 600
- discrete_estimator_weights: array ([1.]) "
- n_trees_discrete and n_trees_real: 1 instead of 600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. My training array, `labels`, had no negatives, it consisted only of labels for one class. Of course the training would terminate immediately!